# Phonegap ios logo icon not set in config.xml, it shows the phonegap logo

Tags: ios, mobile, phonegap-build, phonegap

Here is my config.xml.

I set the icons for android which works fine and already publish to google store, but when same app submit for apple store, they reject the app due to metadata missing.

```
<content src="index.html" />    
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />      
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/Icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/Icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/Icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/Icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/Icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/Icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />    
</platform>
<icon platform="ios" src="icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
<platform name="ios">       
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-20x20@1x.png" width="20" height="20"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-20x20@2x.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-40x40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>      
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-29x29@1x.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-29x29@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>      
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-57x57@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>        
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-29x29@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-72x72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-Small-50x50@1x.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-Small-50x50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-60x60@1x.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-60x60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>        
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-60x60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-72x72@1x.png" width="72" height="72"/>        
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-76x76@1x.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/Icon/ios/icon-App-76x76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>  
</platform> 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<access uri="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

I am using phonegap online build tool to make build.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="icon72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
<icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but I've created a simple tool that allows you to create your own phonegap APP icons simply by uploading your own image!

This tool covers all the icon sizes for both iOS and Android:

https://vps267717.ovh.net/phonegap-assets/